# How to extract string with regex from a df using function and create new column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe

```
Description
a hello from 528-appname
another hellow 269-xyz-appname
```

Desired output

```
Description                            Application
a hello from 528-appname               appname
another hellow 269-xyz-appname         appname
```

What I tried

```
def generate_app_name(row):
    if '528-' in row['Description']:
        return row['Description'].str.contains(r'528-(\w+\w+)')
    if '269-xyz-' in row['Description']:
        return row['Description'].str.contains(r'269-xyz-(\w+\w+)')
    else:
        return('NA')

df['Application'] = df.apply(generate_app_name, axis=1)
```

Error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

528- and 269-xyz- never changes in description. app name is always in this format.

How can i achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.extract` to handle a regex directly on the whole Series:

```
df['Application'] = df['Description'].str.extract(r'(?:528-|269-xyz-)(\w+\b)')
```

Output:

```
                      Description Application
0        a hello from 528-appname     appname
1  another hellow 269-xyz-appname     appname
```